# apparmor: same profile for multiple apps

Tags: ubuntu, apparmor

so I have:

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/python2.7 {
    /** mixrw,
    deny /** lwk,
}

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java {
    /** mixrw,
    deny /** lwk,
}

/var/www/service/usercode/*/a.out {
    /** mixrw,
    #deny /** lwk,
}
```

How could I make it something like this:

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/python2.7 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
/var/www/service/usercode/*/a.out
{
    /** mixrw,
    deny /** lwk,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/python2.7 {
#include <abstractions/mystuff1>
}

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java {
#include <abstractions/mystuff1>
}

/var/www/service/usercode/*/a.out {
#include <abstractions/mystuff1>
}
```

(and then put common stuff in `abstractions/mystuff1`, of course)